# Connection to SQL server from VS DataSet designer not working

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

So, after the last weekend I have been having serious trouble connecting to an SQL database through the Visual Studio environment.

**This is the enviroment**

- My OS is Windows 8.1 Enterprise
- I'm running Visual Studio Community 2013, and develop in VB
- The SQL server is located off site. The version is 12.0.2269. I do not administrate this one, but it is the back-end for the company ERP system so it is running on stable platforms and working well for hundreds of users.
- In VS, I have a connection string set up under Project Settings:

*Data Source=a.b.c.d;Initial Catalog=dbName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=yyy*

(Connection uses ".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server")

**This is what I have tried**

- The SQL server answers to ping
- I can connect to the database through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 12.0.2000.8
- In VS, under Project Settings, I can open the connection string configuration dialog. When I click "Test Connection" everything works fine (*Test connection succeeded*).
- If I start the application I am developing it can connect to the database without problem.
- BUT, if I go to the dataset designer, right click a TableAdapter and select *Preview Data...*, the application hangs for a while and then this error message comes up:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to the SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).*

I should also mention that this worked before last weekend. I have not changed anything to the project. The only change I can see is several windows updates installed during the weekend.

This seems to affect only one particular project. Connections to the same database seems to work well in other solutions.

I have no idea what to do from here. Have this happened to anyone else?

Comment: The messages says the connection attempt was made using Named Pipes. This wouldn't happen if hte `Data Source` was in an IP or FQDN form. Was there a mixup with development settings perhaps? Or was the connection's provider set to Named Pipes? Are you using a *different* connection string from the project settings?

Comment: That confused me a bit as well. 
After writing this post, I fiddled around a bit more. Set up a new (identical) connection string in the project settings, and not it seems to work. I am not sure though. Last week I changed advanced settings for the connection back and forth while troubleshooting, and every now and then it worked for a while but started to struggle after some time.

The connection for the TableAdapter is set to the connection string in project settings.

Answer (score 0):

My connection is like that and work, try with that:

```
Public Function FunctionConnection() As SqlConnection
    FunctionConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TCO_Orders.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    'FunctionConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=")
    Return FunctionConnection
End Function
```